# Is there any up-to-date scheduling/timetabling software available from Debian repos or in deb format?

Tags: debian, software-rec, free-software

I am interested if there is any up-to-date scheduling/timetabling software for personal use (work/daily routine scheduling) available in sid or bullseye Debian repos or just in deb package format.

Comment: Take a look at [fet](https://packages.debian.org/source/buster/fet) debian package. `Timetable Generator - FET is a program for automatically generating the timetable of a school, high-school or university.`

Answer (score 1):

For simple personal things there is [gnome-todo](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Todo). If you want features like gant charts, dependencies or project planing, you probably have to try some web based stuff like [mantis](https://www.mantisbt.org/) – no deb or repo – or [openproject](https://www.openproject.org/) – there is a [package.io repo](https://www.openproject.org/download-and-installation/), probably the buster packages work on bullseye too. (Note that they are for only 64 bit)
There is also a software called `planner` (formerly Mr.Project) which i not used yet, but looks promising. You can find it in the debian repositories.